# Phone call not being simulated in Apple Watch running WatchOS2

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm trying to execute a phone call on a button click on my Apple Watch which is running WatchOS2:

This is the code that runs when the buttons is pressed, which should, according to the docs, simulate a phone call. I'm am using a real Apple Watch, and not a simulator, as well as a real iPhone.

```
- (IBAction)phoneNumberTapped {
    NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel:" stringByAppendingString:self.currentPhoneNumber];
    [[WKExtension sharedExtension] openSystemURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
}
```

However, nothing happens when the button is tapped. I have changed the the `phoneNumber` variable and put my own phone number in place. But nothing still happens. What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known bug. We'll just have to wait for a patch:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4385

Comment: Any idea when it will be patched? It's been almost a month since that post.